# Azure Event Grid with service bus working example

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

Is there any working example of integrating azure event grid with service bus. I'm new to Azure and would like to get it working by using either java or javascript functions.

Appreciate any pointers.
Thanks,

Comment: Integrate in which direction?

Comment: As of now, application needs to poll to service bus for receiving message. Would like to use event grid to poll the messages and deliver to subscription.

Comment: Here are some examples of integrating Azure Service bus with Event grid in .NET. just for your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-example.
You may check this GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/azure-eventgrid for Azure Event Grid with Java SDK.

Comment: Thanks Swikruti! These examples are part of documents, but we have been struggling to get it working. So, I was interested in knowing if anyone has got the integration working. I have using mac and java sdk for the same.